# How do you calculate the information capacity of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, decision-trees, information-theory, theory

Let's say I wanted to train a neural network to teach it the rules in a decision tree, so I generated a dataset by feeding arrays of random numbers into the pre-trained decision tree, and then used the random input arrays as the features in the dataset and the output of the decision tree as the output.

I feed my dataset to the neural network, and start it training. If there are 6 features, logically, a two-layer network can't learn a million-bit decision tree, because there simply isn't enough "information capacity", essentially entropy, in the neural network structure to store such a complex ruleset. With decision trees, calculating entropy is fairly simple. But how would you do it for a neural network?

How would you calculate the minimum size neural network needed to learn a given ruleset?

Comment: It's more of trail and error method to guess what works but experience counts...

Comment: @Aditya I'm asking about the theory and math behind it

Comment: If it's theory you want, read about the [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension#VC_dimension_of_a_neural_network); e.g., in [On the Complexity of Neural Network Classifiers: A Comparison Between Shallow and
Deep Architectures](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2a21/d9a484167c0c1dca6a42077afb7d5fe552a2.pdf) and [Understanding Deep Learning Requires Rethinking Generalization](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-paper-“Understanding-Deep-Learning-Requires-Rethinking-Generalization”-important). Welcome to the site!